# FeatureCollection to geo_shape in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, geojson

#### Whats the right way to translate a geojson FeatureCollection to a es geo_shape?

I have a FeatureCollection looking like this:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [[[1.96, 42.455],[1.985,42.445]]]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [...]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I translate this into the es `geo_shape`.
Currently I just index it like that (dropping `type: Feature` and `type: FeatureCollection` fields) and add a mapping saying:

```
"features": {
    "geometry": {
      "type": "geo_shape"
    }
}
```

This seems to work fine, but feels wrong, as I give an array of `geometry`s.
**Is this okay or would the right way be to translate the `FeatureCollection` to type `geometrycollection`? Which clearly wants multiple `geometry` elements.**

One Followup question, can I do a query a la: `Give me all elements geometrically inside Element X`(where X is also in the index) in one query, without fetching X and than doing multiple follow up queries for each polygon?

Comment: when i try to map it the way you show, i get "Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: No type specified for field [features]". what am I missing? how exactly you map this? thanks

Answer (score 6):

The [GeometryCollection](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html#_ulink_url_http_geojson_org_geojson_spec_html_geometrycollection_geometry_collection_ulink) is probably what you're looking for.

So if you have this:

```json
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [[[1.96, 42.455],[1.985,42.445]]]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [...]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can index it in ES like this:

```
PUT example
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_shape"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /example/doc
{
    "location" : {
        "type": "geometrycollection",
        "geometries": [
            {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [[[1.96, 42.455],[1.985,42.445]]]
            },
            {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [...]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So basically, you simply need to:

- change `FeatureCollection` to `geometrycollection`
- change `features` to `geometries`
- populate the `geometries` array with the `geometry` inner-objects

Regarding your query, you can do it like this:

```
POST /example/_search
{
    "query":{
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "geo_shape": {
                    "location": {
                        "shape": {
                            "type": "envelope",
                            "coordinates" : [[13.0, 53.0], [14.0, 52.0]]
                        },
                        "relation": "within"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `within` relationship returns all documents whose `geo_shape` field is within the geometry given in the query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware of the possibility to transform to the `geometrycollection` format, My question is more why the other works as well and what the advantage is in transforming.

For the query my question was if I can do a query asking for all Elements inside one Element of the index.
So basically getting one indexed Element and asking what is inside that element.

Comment: I don't think the other works as you expect as each feature would be indexed as an independent shape or an array of "unrelated" shapes

Comment: Okay but it seems the indexed element still matches because one of the independent shapes matches, so whats the difference from a search result perpective?

Comment: So I just tried it out, indexing `geometrycollection` and indexing lists of geometries as in my first example, I could not produce different search results..

Comment: Ok, I'd say go for the solution that requires the less effort and changes to the source structure.

Comment: @rincewind did you find any differences between the two approaches (indexing one geomtrycollection vs indexing multiple geometries)?
Also, do you still have some working examples of both data ingestions? 
Thanks!

Comment: @FlorinVîrdol not sure you'll get an answer as rincewind never cared to provide any feedback

Comment: Oh.. thanks, @Val! 
I'm doing a POC to ingest geo data (from GeoJSON or SHP files) in ElasticSearch with Nest client from .NET but i'm struggling to find some proper documentation or some working examples to start with. Do you recommend something?

Comment: @FlorinVîrdol that might sound like an interesting use case. please feel free to create a new question and describe the issues you're going through

Comment: @Val I still have question regarding this - i have opened https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65944884/elastic-storing-geojsons-of-type-featurecollection-and-query