# Elasticsearch get intersection of coordinates

Tags: elasticsearch, intersection

I have the an index `field`, with which, given a set of coordinates for a polygon, I want to get any fields that intersect those coordinates. Is this possible given the structure of the `field` index using `elasticsearch` geo location features? I am using elasticsearch version 7.9

```
{
  "geo_json": {
    "geometry": {
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [
            2.1228971832029644,
            41.3011586218355
          ],
          [
            2.122596585111679,
            41.3012384865674
          ],
          [
            2.1221786804481835,
            41.30191870980272
          ],
          [
            2.1223509744761158,
            41.302042636348716
          ],
          [
            2.1226735685285507,
            41.30192972550523
          ],
          [
            2.1232820963718857,
            41.30165984025794
          ],
          [
            2.1232820963718857,
            41.30131559725024
          ],
          [
            2.1228971832029644,
            41.3011586218355
          ]
        ]
      ],
      "type": "Polygon"
    },
    "properties": null,
    "type": "Feature"
  },
  "name": "Barcelona"
}
```

I have tried the following query, with returned error `"Field [geo_json.geometry.coordinates] is of unsupported type [float]. [geo_shape] query supports the following types [geo_shape,geo_point]"`

```
GET field/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "geo_shape": {
          "geo_json.geometry.coordinates": {
            "shape": {
              "type": "polygon",
              "coordinates": [
                [
                  [
                    2.1228971832029644,
                    41.3011586218355
                  ],
                  [
                    2.122596585111679,
                    41.3012384865674
                  ],
                  [
                    2.1221786804481835,
                    41.30191870980272
                  ],
                  [
                    2.1223509744761158,
                    41.302042636348716
                  ],
                  [
                    2.1226735685285507,
                    41.30192972550523
                  ],
                  [
                    2.1232820963718857,
                    41.30165984025794
                  ],
                  [
                    2.1232820963718857,
                    41.30131559725024
                  ],
                  [
                    2.1228971832029644,
                    41.3011586218355
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            },
            "relation": "intersects"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It surely is possible. Adapting [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65951997/8160318) to your use case:

1. Set up the index mapping

```
PUT geoindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "area": {
        "type": "float"
      },
      "center": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      },
      "geo_json": {
        "type": "geo_shape"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. Add the Barcelona polygon

```
POST geoindex/_doc
{
  "area": 5380.8444064004625,
  "center": [ 2.1227303884100346, 41.30160062909211 ],
  "geo_json": {
    "type": "polygon",
    "coordinates": [[[2.1228971832029644,41.3011586218355],[2.122596585111679,41.3012384865674],[2.1221786804481835,41.30191870980272],[2.1223509744761158,41.302042636348716],[2.1226735685285507,41.30192972550523],[2.1232820963718857,41.30165984025794],[2.1232820963718857,41.30131559725024],[2.1228971832029644,41.3011586218355]]]
  },
  "name": "Barcelona"
}
```

3. Check for the intersection (the query polygon is yellow):

```
POST geoindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "geo_shape": {
      "geo_json": { 
        "relation": "intersects",
        "shape": {
          "type":  "polygon",
          "coordinates": [[[2.122421264648437,41.30061251600798],[2.123579978942871,41.300354591849114],[2.123579978942871,41.30120896171846],[2.122957706451416,41.30129762210163],[2.122421264648437,41.30061251600798]]]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Courtesy of geojson.io]